# multiple ifs in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm a bit stuck with a piece of a query i I have been working on. I need to know if I can use multiple ifs (i.e. if x and y are true then z)

```
SELECT selling_company_id
     , rfp_id
     , offer.id
     , vendor
     , if (company_d.offer.vendor in (select companyName from company.SellingCompanyTable), '1'
     , if (company_d.offer.vendor = '', '0', '0.5')) as 'Vendor Mult'`
```

Situation: I need to return vendor names from another table where those vendors are approved (isApproved ='t')

I would greatly appreciate any feedback or ideas. Thanks

Comment: It's probable that you could do all of this with a `JOIN` instead of a pile of `IF` statements.

Comment: what is the name of the table you are selecting from?

Comment: If your question is only about using mutilple ifs, YES you can use multiple ifs in your SELECT query.  Otherwise your query seems to be partial as it does not even have the Table name for the main query.  You could use LEFT JOIN instead of subquery.

Comment: We are doing data validation via the query. I should've added more of the query for context. See query below

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to join the tables and then do conditions on it. maybe something like this?

```
SELECT o.selling_company_id
     , o.rfp_id
     , o.id
     , o.vendor
     , if(c.id is not NULL, 1, 
            if(o.vendor = '', '0', '0.5')
       ) as 'Vendor Mult'
FROM company_d.offer o
LEFT JOIN company.SellingCompanyTable c ON c.companyName = o.vendor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    selling_company_id,
    rfp_id,
    offer.id,
    vendor,
    IF (company_d.offer.vendor in (SELECT companyName FROM company.SellingCompanyTable),
        '1', IF (company_d.offer.vendor = '', '0', '0.5')) AS 'Vendor Mult',
    format,
    CASE company_d.offer.format WHEN '' THEN '0'
FROM company_d.offer
LEFT JOIN company_d.rfp
ON company_d.rfp.id = company_d.offer.rfp_id
WHERE company_d.offer.buying_company_id = 12565
AND last_modified_at BETWEEN '2014-7-01' AND '2014-12-31';
```

Comment: if you are trying to show more context of the query then edit your question with the query. adding it as an answer to describe the question better is not how you should do it